# Template class method f(const T) don't accept rvalue when T is lvalue reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, lvalue

In the following codes, I have two versions of class `A` instantiated, one is bound to `int` and the other to `int&`.

The method `forward` has `const` in its parameter, so the `int&` version should have the parameter `const int& t`.

A rvalue can be used as `const T&`, however, the compiler complains about binding a non-const lvalue to a rvalue.

I have `const` in the code, so why isn't it working?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T forward(const T t)
    {
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    A<int&> al;
    int i = 1;
    cout << a.forward(1) << endl;  //ok
    cout << al.forward(i) << endl; //ok
    cout << al.forward(1) << endl;  //error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'int'
    return 0;
}
```

The error goes away when I add these codes or replace `A<int&>` with `A<const int&>`.

```
template <typename T>
class A<T&>
{
public:
    T& forward(const T& t)
    {
        return t;
    }
};
```

But I don't understand why.

Comment: A reference cannot be const in c++. That is, you cannot const qualify a reference(like `int &const` is invalid)

Comment: I second the firts comment. Or rather, to expand it: reference is, or can be thought of as always const, i.e.it cannot be re-assigned.

Comment: Thank you for the timely reply. Does that mean when T is `int&`, `const T` is interpreted as `int & const`? If so, is there any other way to make the method accept `const int&`?

Comment: Let me rephrase what `user12002570` has wrote: probably you think you will have function: `int& forward(const int& t)`, but it attempts to create function  `int& forward((int&) const t)` what is invalid. This is like difference between types `const int *` and `int * const`. In case of pointers it is valid and in case of references second version doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References cannot be **const-qualified** in C++. This means that your attempt to add a **top-level const** to `int&` does not work(i.e., ignored).

This essentially means that the parameter of `A<int&>::forward` is of type `int&` which can only bind to an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

For `A<int> a;` `forward` will take argument of type `const int`.
However, for `A<int&> al;` acts as if `forward` were to take argument of type `int& const` which is not possible.

You can provide two functions and SFINAE-away one of them, e.g. this way:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T forward(const T t) requires(!std::is_reference_v<T>)
    {
        return t;
    }

    auto forward(
        std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>> t) -> decltype(t) 
        requires(std::is_reference_v<T>)
    {
        return t;
    }

};


int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    A<int> a;
    A<int&> al;
    int i = 1;
    cout << a.forward(1) << '\n';  //ok
    cout << al.forward(i) << '\n'; //ok
    cout << al.forward(1) << '\n'; //risky
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, decltype(al.forward(i))>);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note that this gets risky for rvalues and requires more thorough implementation.**

https://godbolt.org/z/Gv494G6bv